# My program won't store cookies. [Kind of duplicate]

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am trying to do cookies in JavaScript but when I run the snippet from [W3](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) in Visual Studios but it won't work. I've even tried the one from [Moxilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) too.

I've run the snippet several times, and no such luck. I've tried it on a new tab. Still, have nothing. I have tried setting `document.cookie` to something like what Mozilla says you can do but it doesn't work. It also for whatever reason doesn't work here but it's whatever I suppose. The only difference is that it'll come up with an error, and a error I would never expect.
Here's the sample;
(The colors are set to that because I was looking at a white screen for a while and it was hurting my eyes.)

```js
 document.cookie = "name=oeschger; SameSite=None; Secure";
    document.cookie = "favorite_food=tripe; SameSite=None; Secure";

    function showCookies() {
      const output = document.getElementById("cookies");
      output.textContent = `> ${document.cookie}`;
    }

    function clearOutputCookies() {
      const output = document.getElementById("cookies");
      output.textContent = "";
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <script>
    //This is where the JavaScript would go.
  </script>
  <body style="background-color: gray;">
    <button onclick="showCookies()">Show Cookies</button>
    <button onclick="clearOutputCookies()">Clear</button>
    <br>
    <code style="color:burlywood" id="cookies"></code>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: We can't help you all that much unless you can show us a [mre] of the behavior you're describing.

Comment: Also, if it's "*kind of duplicate*", what is it a duplicate of, and why would you need to post a brand new question altogether? What makes it different from any of the previously-posted flavors of this question? Including that level of detail would be helpful for potential answerers as well.

Comment: Does the code work if you run it in a browser instead of Visual Studio?

Comment: @Barmar No. I tried it on Chrome and on a file. Neither work. I have tried it on Mozilla but that's the only other place I've tried it.

Comment: And @esqew I have edited my post to give you a clearer idea.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behavior you describe using the code you provided here in my local copy of Chrome with the resultant page being served via Live Server in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Just go to a new tab and type into the console "document.cookie =" and whatever you want it to say and then click enter. Next type in "document.cookie".  I can't get it to show what I just entered.